# How to remove an element attribute from a clone element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I'm able to clone a row using the following jquery code below successfully

```
$selectedRow.closest("tr").clone(true);
```

Within this clone `tr`, I need to remove the `rowspan` attribute from this `td`...

```
<td class="column1" rowspan="1">Testing this column</td>
```

I tried the following code

```
$selectedRow.closest("tr").clone(true).find(".column1").removeAttr("rowspan");
```

The problem with the above code is that it over shows this but it does remove the `rowspan` attribute:

```
<td class="column1">Testing this column</td>
```

I need it to show everything as in the previous code I wrote above:

```
$selectedRow.closest("tr").clone(true);
```

Comment: It appears you're applying the `removeAttr` to the wrong element – namely the original one, not the cloned.

Comment: what does "***is that it over shows this***" mean ? You mention that the rowspan **is** removed. so what is the problem exactly ?

Comment: You're creating a clone, then removing the attribute, but you're not storing the clone anywhere, what are you expecting ?

Comment: @lxg no he is not. the `clone` returns the new element and since he is chaining the calls the `removeAttr` is applied to the correct element (*the `td` inside the cloned `tr`*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - That's true, but creating a clone, then using `find()` discards the clone,  it's not stored anywhere and the chained collection of functions returns `.column1` so it makes no sense.

Comment: @adeneo it does not discard it. with an `.end()` you would return to it.

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - Yes you would, but the OP doesn't seem to be clear on what a clone is, or how to store it, so not sure it would help much ?

Comment: @adeneo i do not disagree that the OP does not do anything with the clone in the posted code. I was just pointing out to @lxg that said the `removeAttr` was applied to the wrong element..

Comment: perhaps the misunderstanding of the OP is that he has to insert that cloned element in the DOM with `.append`, `.insertAfter` etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `end` method which ends the current filtering operation and returns the previous set which is the cloned `tr`.

```
var $clonedRow = $selectedRow.closest("tr")
                             .clone(true)
                              // find the `.column1` descendant of the cloned row
                             .find(".column1") 
                             .removeAttr("rowspan")
                             // end the current filtering operation 
                             // and return the cloned `tr`
                             .end();
```

Note that if the `$selectedRow` refers to a `tr` element `closest` doesn't do anything in this case, as it starts from testing the element itself and then traverses up through its ancestors in the DOM.

Comment: How would `.end()` solve the problem that the attribute isn't removed?

Comment: @lxg `removeAttr` should remove the attribute, I interpreted the question as "how can I end the current filtering operation and get the modified, cloned `tr` element"!.

Comment: I see … makes sense. Maybe the question should be put on hold to be clarified by the OP.

Comment: wow, the end() method fix this problem... I need to read more on this end() method. Super Thanks Vohuman for the stress release...

Answer (score 0):

```
var $newClone = $selectedRow.closest("tr").clone(true);
$newClone.find(".column1").removeAttr("rowspan");
```

Comment: This solution does not work. It returns only the <td class="column1">Testing this column</td> and missing the complete row with the <tr></tr> and others <td></td>